# What's The Difference Between type <Name> <dataType> and type <Name> = <dataType>

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang. I'm sorry but I'm still confused on what's the difference between:

```
type <Name> <dataType>
```

and

```
type <Name> = <dataType>
```

Here's an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var (
        strWord Word
        strText Text
    )
    strWord = "gopher"
    strText = "golang"

    fmt.Printf("strWord = %s, Type of Value = %T\n", strWord, strWord)
    fmt.Printf("strText = %s, Type of Value = %T\n", strText, strText)

}

type Word string

type Text = string
```

Output

```
strWord = gopher, Type of Value = main.Word
strText = golang, Type of Value = string
```

Then, when should we use between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a type declaration, the second is a type alias

### Type declaration

Docs: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations

This allows you to create a new distinct type `<Name>`, with the underlying type `<datatype>`.

You could define something like:

```
type Password string
```

And then reimplement the `String()` method for it so that it's never accidentally printed.

```
func (p Password) String() string {
    return "<redacted>"
}
```

### Type alias

Type aliases are used mostly for iterative refactoring, where moving a type from one package to another would create too large a change / break too many things.

This article explains some usecases for it:

https://talks.golang.org/2016/refactor.article

But it essentially allows you to use one type *as* another.

```
package mypackage
type Foo struct {}


package other
type Bar = mypackage.Foo
```

You can now use `other.Bar` and `mypackage.Foo` interchangeably. They are the same type, with different names. Whereas type declaration is a *new* type.

Comment: Thanks for the example & detailed explanation :)